# Kafka Pod doesn't start on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine

I followed this [tutorial](https://dojoblog.dellemc.com/dojo/deploy-kafka-cluster-kubernetes/#comment-9676) and when I tried to run it on GKE I was not able to start `kafka` pod.

It returns `CrashLoopBackOff` all the time. And I don't know how to show pod error logs.

Here is the result when I hit `kubectl describe pod my-pod-xxx`:

```
Name:           kafka-broker1-54cb95fb44-hlj5b
Namespace:      default
Node:           gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-zgcx/10.146.0.4
Start Time:     Thu, 25 Oct 2018 11:40:21 +0900
Labels:         app=kafka
                id=1
                pod-template-hash=1076519600
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger=LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container kafka
Status:         Running
IP:             10.48.8.10
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kafka-broker1-54cb95fb44
Containers:
  kafka:
    Container ID:   docker://88ee6a1df4157732fc32b7bd8a81e329dbdxxxx9cbe614689e775d183dbcd61
    Image:          wurstmeister/kafka
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://wurstmeister/kafka@sha256:4f600a95fa1288f7b1xxxxxa32ca00b4fb13b83b31533fa6b40499bd9bdf192f
    Port:           9092/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Thu, 25 Oct 2018 14:35:32 +0900
      Finished:     Thu, 25 Oct 2018 14:35:51 +0900
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  37
    Requests:
      cpu:  100m
    Environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT:       9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:  35.194.100.32
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:     zoo1:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID:             1
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS:         topic1:3:3
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-w6s7n (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-w6s7n:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-w6s7n
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                From                                                   Message
  ----     ------   ----               ----                                                   -------
  Warning  BackOff  5m (x716 over 2h)  kubelet, gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-zgcx  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling  36s (x38 over 2h)  kubelet, gke-xxxdefault-pool-f9e313ed-zgcx  pulling image "wurstmeister/kafka"
```

I noticed that on the first run it is going well but after that,`Node` is changing status to `NotReady` and `kafka pod` is entering the `CrashLoopBackOff`
state.

Here is the log before it goes down:

`Type    Reason                  Age   From                                                   Message
  ----    ------                  ----  ----                                                   -------
  Normal  Scheduled               5m    default-scheduler                                      Successfully assigned kafka-broker1-54cb95fb44-wwf2h to gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-8mr6
  Normal  SuccessfulMountVolume   5m    kubelet, gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-8mr6  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-w6s7n"
  Normal  Pulling                 5m    kubelet, gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-8mr6  pulling image "wurstmeister/kafka"
  Normal  Pulled                  5m    kubelet, gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-8mr6  Successfully pulled image "wurstmeister/kafka"
  Normal  Created                 5m    kubelet, gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-8mr6  Created container
  Normal  Started                 5m    kubelet, gke-xxx-default-pool-f9e313ed-8mr6  Started container
  Normal  NodeControllerEviction  38s   node-controller                                        Marking for deletion Pod kafka-broker1-54cb95fb44-wwf2h from Node gke-dev-centurion-default-pool-f9e313ed-8mr6`

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my pod and how can I catch the error for pod failure?

Comment: I notice that at the first time it going well but after that one `Node` changed status to `NotReady` and `kafka pod` returned `CrashLoopBackOff`

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that my cluster's nodes have not enough resources.
After creating a new cluster with more memory, it works.